# For half integral weight newform does the Shimura correspondance give a newform?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modular-forms

in number theory,
half integral wieght newforms implies the shimura correspondance is it also newforms ?
namely,
if  $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n)q^n\in S_{k+1/2}^{new}(N,\chi)$ is half integral newforms then  $f_t(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_t(n)q^n\in S_{2k}(\Gamma(2N),\chi^2)$ given by the shimura correspendance with \begin{equation}
a_{t}(n)=\underset{d\mid n}{\sum}\chi_{t,N}(d)d^{k-1}a(\frac{n^2t}{d^2})\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
where $\chi_{t,N_i}$ denotes the character defined by $\chi_{t,N}(d):=\chi(d)(\frac{(-1)^{k}N^2t}{d})$.  is it   $f_t$ also newforms ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can tell if a modular form is a newform just by looking at the Dirichlet series: multiplicative coefficients, right functional equational equation (from which you can read the level). And the properties of the Dirichlet series is how Shimura proves that it is a weight $2k$ level N modular form. So perhaps just look at Shimura's paper?